# Can I move an App between SD card and Ram?

Tags: internal-storage, sd-card

Is it possible to move an app to an SD card even if it cannot be used and then move it to internal memory to use it? Android 11 Galaxy A20 128GB SD card 32GB internal memory. Most of the answers I see are about 10 years old. Has anything changed?

Comment: Just a note: your title is a bit misleading as you can not move something to RAM. Some device manufacturer implement a feature called app hibernate or freeze where you can move apps you don't use of a time somewhere else, e.g. to the cloud (I think this was an LG phone not sure what other manufacturer provide something similar). But such a solution needs to be built into the phone.

Comment: not sure what you asking. Samsung devices don't support [adoptable-storage](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/adoptable-storage/info). you can save a copy of apk\* on MicroSD Card so you can install or uninstall apk any time without internet connection (\*[adb backup](https://www.xda-developers.com/google-releases-separate-adb-and-fastboot-binary-downloads) required once)

Comment: When I install programs, they are initially installed on internal memory. I use a program called AppMgr III. It will move some apps to the SD card, but quite a few it won't. I was looking for a way to move some of those apps to the SD card even if they no longer work.  If the APK files can be moved to the SD card and then reinstalled when I need them, that may be the best solution.  I did discover that the amount of space taken up by the APK files is substantial.  For now, just deleting them freed up several Gbs of space.